# Test asynchronous user interface action on Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I have the following test below, wherein I update one text field, after which an API call is made, and following that, I expect the other text field to have the same value based on the API response. However, it keeps failing with the error `Expected '0' to equal '2'.` I am expecting a result of 2 = 2 based on the response from the API. Any idea how can I fix this?

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-post-dgcuur

**Test**

```
it('should successfuly convert A to A', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        let fromAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#fromAmountValue')).nativeElement;
        expect(fromAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('0');
        let toAmountValueEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toAmountValue')).nativeElement;
        expect(toAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('0');
        fromAmountValueEl.value = '2'
        fromAmountValueEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        fromAmountValueEl.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
          'key': 'Enter'
        }));
        tick();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          fixture.detectChanges();
          expect(fromAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('2');
          expect(toAmountValueEl.value).toEqual('2');
        });
      });
    }));
```

**View**

```
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="number" placeholder="0" [(ngModel)]="fromAmount"
        (keyup)="updateRates()" id="fromAmountValue">
      <select class="form-control form-control-lg" id="fromCurrency">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      </select>

      <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="number" placeholder="0" [(ngModel)]="toAmount"
        (keyup)="updateRates()" id="toAmountValue">
      <select class="form-control form-control-lg" [(ngModel)]="toCurrency" id="toCurrency">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
      </select>
```

**Controller**

```
  updateRates() {
    this.postSubscription = this.post().subscribe((data) => {
      if(data) {
        this.result = data;

        if (this.toCurrency == "GBP") {
          this.toAmount = this.fromAmount;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think your problem is, when you check if 2 is = 2, API call hasn't been made yet, and default value of toAmount is "0". so it gets the value "0" from there.

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: are you set on unit testing using KeyboardEvent or you are fine with it not being in the test?

Comment: Whatever works initially I guess, it would be easier to test with the keyboard event

Comment: Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-post-dgcuur